# CentOS and PXE Boot

Tags: networking, centos, centos5, pxe-boot

I am working on setting up a PXE boot server based upon a minimal installation of CentOS 5.6.  I have installed CentOS 5.6 with the the first CD using the minimal installation method.  Next, I followed the tutorial listed  [here](http://www.r71.nl/kb/technical/300-centos-fedora-pxe-boot-server-setup) to get the PXE components installed and running.  This all seems to be working correctly.  However, I would like to take advantage of using a graphic as part of the boot screen.  It is my understanding that vesamenu.c32 is required to do this.  However, I am not able to locate this file within the installed package for CentOS.  I have tried in the past to copy over the vesamenu.c32 file from [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/syslinux/) without success.  I was curious how I could get a graphical boot menu setup with this environment.

Comment: The following is the output from yum info syslinux: Arch x86_64, Version 3.11, Release 4.

Comment: The aim of this setup is primarily for PXE booting ISOs of various system utilities (UBCD, memtest) and rescue disks (AV live CDs, etc.) used within our help desk.  It will also be used to PXE boot Windows PE and our Symantec Ghost ISO that we have built.  Lastly, this will need to be something that can be managed and updated over time by non-Linux folks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to network boot a lot of clients?  If so, I'd suggest you take a look at DRBL.  This can automate a lot of the PXE/NFS setup for you, and makes the entire process pretty painless.

If you are trying to do installs via PXE, DRBL will also greatly simplify this process.

Comment: Thanks for the info about DRBL.  We are mainly looking for a simple PXE setup such that we can boot some ISO images of Windows PE, UBCD, DBAN, memtest, and our version of Symantec Ghost.  I am not sure if the solution you offer will allow us to do this.  Also, we are needing something that does not have a lot of development time and is easy for non-linux folks to manage and maintain over time.

Answer (score 0):

You want cobbler: https://fedorahosted.org/cobbler/

Comment: Thanks for the info about Cobbler.  We are mainly looking for a simple PXE setup such that we can boot some ISO images of Windows PE, UBCD, DBAN, memtest, and our version of Symantec Ghost.  I am not sure if the solution you offer will allow us to do this.  Also, we are needing something that does not have a lot of development time and is easy for non-linux folks to manage and maintain over time.